# Bootstrap/CSS - How to arrange 2 cols on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

First of all, I am using Bootstrap.
I need to order 2 cols on mobile.
This is how they are arranged in my code:

```
<!--First col-->
<div class="col-sm-6">
<!--Content--> 
</div>

<!--Second col-->
<div class="col-sm-6">
<!--Content--> 
</div>
```

As expected on mobile the First col will be placed on top of the Second col (block). On a bigger screen the First col will be on the left and the Second col on the right (inline-block). I want to change the places of the two cols only for smaller screens so that the Second col will be before the First col like this:

```
<!--Second col-->
<div class="col-sm-6">
<!--Content--> 
</div>

<!--First col-->
<div class="col-sm-6">
<!--Content--> 
</div>
```

In this case the Second col will be on top of the First col on a smaller screen. I want this to be only for mobile.
So how can I achieve this? A solution or advice would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap have their own classes for dealing with the order of the columns which deals exactly with what you want.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Search for "Column Ordering".

For example:

```html
<!--Second col-->
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">
    <!--Content--> 
</div>

<!--First col-->
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
    <!--Content--> 
</div>
```

In the example above we're working from "mobile first" layout. So we'd put the second column first and then using the bootstrap push and pull classes we can re-arrange the order on the higher break points.

Nb: A good tip I learnt from industry professionals was to start coding your 'layout' from mobile first then work your way up. In most cases at least.

Comment: beside posting link, you should also write your own answer explaining the code . if that link is down for some reason, your post will not be much of use.

Comment: Almost, you need to put the second col first so that it will be above the first col on mobile. Everything else is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `display:flex` css property for the same. [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/H7d4D5q2sl)

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex-wrap">
<!--First col-->
<div class="col-sm-6 flex-item1">
<!--Content--> 
</div>

<!--Second col-->
<div class="col-sm-6 flex-item2">
<!--Content--> 
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flex-wrap {
    display: flex;
}
.flex-item1 //First col{
    order: 1; 
}
.flex-item2 //Second col{
    order: 2; 
}
@media screen and (max-width: 676px) {
    .flex-wrap {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .flex-item1 //First col - changed the position to 2{
        order: 2;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .flex-item2 //Second col position changed to 2{
        order: 1;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

You can mention the exact mobile phone with the `@media Screen (max-width:676px)`

Answer (score 0):

Use media query on mobile try to this

```css
div.md-right{
float:right
}
div.md-left{
float:left;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) { 
  div.md-right,
  div.md-left{
    float:none;
    width:100%;
    }
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!--First col-->
        <div class="col-sm-6 md-right">
            <!--Content--> First col
        </div>

        <!--Second col-->
        <div class="col-sm-6 md-left">
            <!--Content--> Second col
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

you can set with as per your need